# user input count down timer using thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a GUI composed of 1 button, 1 text field, 1 label. It
converts string to int from text field. decrement it by 1. print on label

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        while (runner == Thread.currentThread()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Step 1");
                int count = Integer.valueOf(txt.getText());
                System.out.println("Step 2");
                while (count != 0) {
                    count--;
                    lblcount.setText("Time Left is " + Integer.toString(count));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Step 3");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("error of some sort here step 4");
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timed2 dd = new Timed2();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve) {
        Object source = eve.getSource();
        if (source.equals(btncount)) {
            run();
        }
    }
```

console error

```
Step 1
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)

    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)

    at timed2.Timed2.run(Timed2.java:42)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

how do i change the thread to read the text box after user inputs number and not before thus giving me this error which means it counts down nothing

Comment: Please include a problem statement.  Saying "this simply won't function" isn't much different than "hey, my code is broken, come fix it."

Comment: the program runs and gives no errors . but it never reaches the catch statement . it only prints out step 1 on the console meaning it never reaches step2 .so if i get no error what is it that prevents the code from compiling ....?

Answer (score 0):

Also, it seems it cannot parse empty string

```
 For input string: ""
    at 
 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

so maybe check in debug if any value is sent from the GUI.